# MySql retorna LocalDate um dia atrás

Tags: mysql, jsf, java-8

Não estou conseguindo identificar um problema utilizando Java LocalDate com MySql Date.
Ao salvar uma data no meu banco MySql ela salva na data correta, por exemplo: 2019-05-24.

Ao fazer uma pesquisa utilizando criteriaQuery, ela encontra o registro esperado na data, porém está me retornando o dia anterior.
Pensei que poderia ser a forma como estou exibindo a data no meu conversor:

```
@FacesConverter("localDateFacesConverter")
public class LocalDateFacesConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String stringValue) {
        if (null == stringValue || stringValue.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        LocalDate localDate = null;
        try {
            localDate = LocalDateHelper.strToLocalDate(stringValue.trim(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            throw new ConverterException("O formato da data deve ser 2015/11/15");
        }
        return localDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object instant) {
        if (null == instant) {
            return "";
        }
        if (component instanceof javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText) {
            if (instant instanceof LocalDate) {
                return LocalDateHelper.formataLocalDate((LocalDate) instant, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            } else if (instant instanceof LocalDateTime) {
                return LocalDateHelper.formataLocalDateTime((LocalDateTime) instant, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            }
            return LocalDateHelper.formataInstant((Instant) instant, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        }
        if (instant instanceof LocalDate) {
            return LocalDateHelper.formataLocalDate((LocalDate) instant, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        } else if (instant instanceof LocalDateTime) {
            return LocalDateHelper.formataLocalDateTime((LocalDateTime) instant, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        }
        return LocalDateHelper.formataInstant((Instant) instant, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    }
}
```

Tentei de tudo mas não estou conseguindo resolver o problema.
Alguém já passou por isso e tem uma solução?

Comment: Provavelmente problema de fuso horário.

Comment: @anonimo Pois também pensei que seria, mas não é, esta tudo configurado para o fuso horário correto, em todas as instancias, no banco, no servidor de aplicações e no código.

Comment: @anonimo Continuei procurando um possível problema com o fuso horário e encontrei. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Depois de realizar vários testes, encontrei relatos sobre o mesmo problema e o resolvi configurando o time_zone do MySQL.

```
set @@time_zone = '-03:00'
set @@session.time_zone = '-03:00'
```

é necessário adicionar o default-time-zone no no arquivo de configurações do MySQL para que ao iniciar este seja o padrão adotado. O arquivo está em (/etc/my.cnf) adicionar a seguinte propriedade no final do arquivo:

> default-time-zone='-03:00'

Também configurei a propriedade URL do DS do GlassFish da seguinte forma:

```
  <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/conciliador?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=America/Sao_Paulo"></property>
```

Com isso passou a funcionar perfeitamente.